# How can I access to my content projected directive?

Tags: angular

I have a `form-field` component. Inside I am projecting content - input html element. On that element I attached directive called `autoCompletition`.

```
 <app-form-field>
     <input [id]="autoCompleteSearchInput" [formControl]='search' type="text" autoComplete="off"
        class='input-underline search-bar idented-text' placeholder="Enter" autoCompletion 
        #custom="autoCompletion"/>
 </<app-form-field>
```

```
<form>
    <p>form-field works!</p>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

I need to access to the directive, which is hosted on the input. So if I give it the name:
`#custom="autoCompletition`
I can access in my component like this:

```
 @ContentChild('custom')
  directive?: ElementRef;

 ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log('this.directive);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the directive is hardcoded - so it is called `custom`. I need a way to make it customizable - so it should work with any name.

From the parent component if I call it `#someOtherName="autoCompletition"` and I need to acess the reference of that directive from `app-form-field` automatically.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by the class name and not the given name

```
  // assuming a directive like so
  @Directive({...})
  class AutoCompleteDirective {...}
 
  // in the component
  @ContentChild(AutoCompleteDirective)
  directive!: AutoCompleteDirective;
```

Comment: @codebrach but how can i listen to changes in the directive ?

Comment: if by changes in the directive you mean in the existing instance of the directive then you can call methods that exist on your directive.

you can get the actual instance of the directive (updated the code)